# HTML/VBA dropdown menu and download the data

Tags: html, excel, vba, download

I have a small problem with a VBA routine through which I would like to download only the list of championships (without matches) of the day from the website https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/
With the help of the QHarr user I was able to change the drop-down menu from "Kick off times" to "Leagues" so as to have the list of championships in alphabetical order.
However, when I do the iteration in the table to download the name of the championships (I repeat without the matches) these are taken in the order of "Kick off times" and not of "Leagues". How could I do?
Hoping to be clear, I thank everyone who can help me. This is the code that I wrote:

```
Sub Download()

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Application.StatusBar = "Download Elenco Campionati odierni in corso..."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/"
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop
        '-------------------------------------------------------------
        'Thanks to User QHarr

        .document.querySelector("#nr-all [value='2']").Selected = True

        Set evt = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        evt.initEvent "change", True, False
        .document.querySelector("#nr-all select").dispatchEvent evt
        '-------------------------------------------------------------
    End With

    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

    i = 9 'Riga di inizio copia dati
    j = 0 'Colonna di inizio copia dati

    Range("A10:A1005").ClearContents 'Pulisce la Zona dove saranno incollati i dati

    Set mycoll = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("table-main js-nrbanner-t")


    For Each myItm In mycoll

        For Each trtr In myItm.Rows
            If trtr.classname = "js-tournament" Then
                inizio = InStr(trtr.innerHTML, "href=") + 6
                fine = InStr(trtr.innerHTML, "><i") - 1
                fedhtml = Trim(Mid(trtr.innerHTML, inizio, fine - inizio))
                campionato = Split(Replace(fedhtml, "/soccer/", ""), "/")
                campionato = Trim(campionato(1))
                    Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = trtr.innerText
                    Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Select
                    Selection.RowHeight = 15
                    i = i + 1
            End If
        Next trtr

    Next myItm

    'Chiusura IE
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

    Calculate

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Davide Your For Each myItm In mycoll loop runs 2x because node "table-main js-nrbanner-t" occurs 2x in ie.document. 1st as standard default order, 2nd as user clicked order. It's enough to read 2nd loop only and will be OK. Try something like this:

```
SecondOccur = False
For Each myitm In mycoll
    If SecondOccur Then
        For Each trtr In myitm.Rows
            If trtr.classname = "js-tournament" Then
                inizio = InStr(trtr.innerHTML, "href=") + 6
                fine = InStr(trtr.innerHTML, "><i") - 1
                fedhtml = Trim(Mid(trtr.innerHTML, inizio, fine - inizio))
                campionato = Split(Replace(fedhtml, "/soccer/", ""), "/")
                campionato = Trim(campionato(1))
                    Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = trtr.innerText
                    Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Select
                    Selection.RowHeight = 15
                    i = i + 1
            End If
        Next trtr
    End If
    SecondOccur = True
Next myitm
```